# Trying to setup mongo db in GitHub action Pipeline

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, github-actions

```
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.4.23
    env:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
    options: >-
      --health-cmd mongo
      --health-interval 10s
      --health-timeout 5s
      --health-retries 5
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

Tried setting up the above pipeline but getting the error- Error response from daemon: create ./mongo-init.js: "./mongo-init.js" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path

Answer (score 0):

as the error says, you should use an **absolute** path and not **relative** one,

you can achieve that using [${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) which would provide the default location of your repository after using the **checkout** action, therefore you should also have to add a [checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) step to your GitAction workflow

**concluding:**

add to your `workflow.yaml` the checkout step under relevant job

```
jobs:
  your_job:
    name: your_job_name
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

perform this change to your docker-compose file

```
 volumes:
      - ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```